# RecyclerView's GridLayoutManager - Alternating 1 and 2 column rows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I want 1 image in the first row and 2 images in the second row and repeated so on..
I Want recyclerview to be like this

[image: screenshot]

Comment: user header in list view or recyclic view

Comment: So these layouts will appear alternately? If yes then I'll suggest using LinearLayout manager rather than GridLayout manager. If you want I can post my answer.

Comment: @bhavesh yes you can post your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    GridLayoutManager layout_manager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 2);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return (position % 3 == 0 ? 2 : 1);
            }
        });

/* Custom Adapter */

        Adapter contact_adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, all_contacts_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layout_manager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contact_adapter);
```

Comment: This answer requires more details. See «[explaining entirely]» thread (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: The thing is, quality checker bot flagged your answer as a potentially low quality answer. Moderators are given the choice to suggest removal of such answers, I did not though but suggest you to add relevant explanation because your answer might solve the problem and all users might not be comfortable with your code. Did you follow the link ?

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch(mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)){
                case MyAdapter.TYPE_HEADER:
                    return 2;
                case MyAdapter.TYPE_ITEM:
                    return 1;
                default:
                    return -1;
            }
        }
    });

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

and set your items' type as header or item in your adapter

Answer (score -1):

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView =
    (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(this, arrayList);
if (mRecyclerView != null) {
  mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
  mRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
}
```

Comment: 1) Please explain your answers, not just dump code. 2) This does not appear to alternate 1 and 2 columns as the question asked for